# Character formula for real representations

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

For an irreducible representation of a complex semisimple Lie algebra the Weyl character formula is well known. For an irreducible real representation of a real semisimple Lie algebra is there a Weyl kind of character formula known ?

Comment: Have you checked what happens when you complexify both the Lie algebra and the scalars of its representation, and then try to translate that back to information in the real-real setting?

Comment: When you complexify the an irreducible real representation then it is either irreducible or can be decomposed as sum of an irreducible representation and its conjugate and in the later case the character is $ch(\lambda)+ch(\sigma(\lambda))$ where $\sigma$ is a Cartan involution. Now the question is how do you translate back to the real setting ? Is there a way to get a character formula directly without complexifying the representation ?